# What is use of 802.11 open authentication req/response frames

Tags: wifi, access-point

As far as I know, the 802.11 open authentication request/response frame is used for WEP(open/shared key) security.
Nowadays we are not using WEP security, then why these two frames are exchanged after probe response.

Can someone plz clarify that why 802.11 open authentications req/res frames are used in WPA/WPA2-akm-802.1x/psk security and in which scenario 802.11 open authentication response frame fails(status code-0x0001).

Answer (score 0):

Mainly backwards compatibility. Wi-Fi technology is 20 years old but you can still connect an old 11b client to a fully fledged 2020 access point (and vice versa).